# How to add css style to new element

Tags: css

I have a wordpress. I use a one page theme so When I scroll down, the wordpress create a sticky menu. By default I have:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div class="header-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="btn-menu"></div>
                    <nav id="mainnav" class="mainnav" role="navigation">
                        <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
                            <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-6">
                                    <a href="/">Strona główna</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-611" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-611">
                                    <a href="#">Cennik</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-501" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-501">
                                    <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

When I scroll down the jquery add float-header class to header:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header fixed float-header" role="banner">
```

So why my code dosen't work ?

```
.float-header > div > div > div > div > .mainnav > div > ul > li > a{
    color: black;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why don't you use like that `.mainnav ul li a` or `.float-header .mainnav ul li a`

Comment: It work perfect... show us your jquery code

Comment: When i try it works. My guess is that another CSS rule takes priority upon yours, either because it comes after in CSS loading order, or because it has `!important`. I suggest inspecting the element in your browser developper tools to check which rules apply, and eventually try with `color: black !important;` to check if it works (using `!important` should be your last resort though, it's quite annoying not being able to override later because of that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to run it , it works perfectly...

So I guess it because your css was overriden by other that the reason I **use `!important`.. to perevent override..**

Learn about `!important`:https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

```css
.float-header .mainnav ul li a{
    color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header fixed float-header" role="banner">
    <div class="header-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="btn-menu"></div>
                    <nav id="mainnav" class="mainnav" role="navigation">
                        <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
                            <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-6">
                                    <a href="/">Strona główna</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-611" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-611">
                                    <a href="#">Cennik</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="menu-item-501" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-501">
                                    <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: try `color: red!important;`

Comment: I tried this before You write and this is it! Thanks.

Comment: @Kaddath I edited answer (if you think  it nedded improve I really appricate if you do it)thanke you

Comment: sorry i acquired the edit priviledge only yesterday, that's not something i'm used to think about, will do in the future ;)

Comment: don't use `!important` if you don't know what exactly it is!

Comment: @wdetac that the reason i attach link that learn when it good to use and when not